# Объединение вывода двух запросов

Tags: sql, oracle

Приветвую. Необходимо объединить объединить два запроса в один:

```
SELECT * FROM "СОРЕВН"; 

SELECT * 
FROM   "СОРЕВН" 
where  "ВРЕМЯ_ПРОВЕД" between to_date('2016/11/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
                          and to_date('2016/11/10', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Необходима дупликация данных, что-бы последовательно выводился список всех соревнований, а потом список соревнований в указанный период. Модель данных прикладываю. UNION не подходит, так как он исключает повторяющиеся данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужны все данные, в том числе и повторяющиеся, то используйте `UNION ALL`.

> The UNION operator returns only distinct rows that appear in either
>   result, while the UNION ALL operator returns all rows.

[Ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)